# How do you search a non-indexed folder in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

Is there any way to search a folder in Finder that hasn't been indexed? I have an external HDD that I don't need indexed, but when I am search for a file, it brings up no results because it isn't indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Find Any File](http://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/)

is a good, inexpensive search utility that does not use Spotlight and will enable you to perform these kinds of searches.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in Finder as it depends on Spotlight for it's search database, you can do it with one of the Finder replacements like [Pathfinder](http://www.cocoatech.com/).